# Ansible best practice for updating placeholder settings?

Tags: django, deployment, settings, config, ansible

I have an application configuration file, for example in Django there is a settings.py file. Within that file are database connection settings like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

And then in environment specific group_vars files I have some variables that store values that will replace the ones in the settings.py file during a deploy role task.

What is the best practice for the above scenario? Should 'db_name' be something like '[DB_NAME_PLACEHOLDER]' and then Ansible replaces that with a specified variable from the proper group_vars file?

**UPDATE**

I instead used an approach where I turned settings.py into a jinja2 template and now have a settings.py.j2 file in the templates directory of my deploy role. Then I made a task in my deploy role to use the template module to place the file in the right place.

I also removed settings.py from my django code base, as it is now being written during an ansible deploy play. I had to then edit my .gitignore to ignore changes to the settings.py file. This seems like a hack-y workaround. Maybe place settings.py outside of the django source and then modify DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable?

Comment: Templating your `settings.py` file is a good way to go. I see nothing "hack-y" about it. You can move your _update_ section into a proper answer below.

Comment: +1, use template (settings.py.j2) with if jinja2 statements. In the playbook check that you setup the variables or die.